# JGit: read the content of a file at a commit in a branch

Tags: java, jgit

I want to read the content of a file at a certain commit in a certain branch: I am currently, using this code to read the content of a file at a certain commit ignoring the branch.

```
    public static String readContentOfFileAtCommit(String commitStr, String fileName)
        throws IOException {

    String content = null;
    ObjectId lastCommitId = currentRepo.resolve(commitStr);

    try (RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk(currentRepo)) {
        RevCommit commit = revWalk.parseCommit(lastCommitId);
        RevTree tree = commit.getTree();

        try (TreeWalk treeWalk = new TreeWalk(currentRepo)) {
            treeWalk.addTree(tree);
            treeWalk.setRecursive(true);
            treeWalk.setFilter(PathFilter.create(fileName));
            if (!treeWalk.next()) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Did not find expected file:" + fileName);
            }

            ObjectId objectId = treeWalk.getObjectId(0);
            ObjectLoader loader = currentRepo.open(objectId);
            content = new String(loader.getBytes());
        }

        revWalk.dispose();
    }

    return content;
}
```

My goal is to get the content of a file at a certain commit that is done on a certain branch.

Comment: Please clarify your question. What is the expected outcome of the snippet and what is the actual outcome?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: While a commit is usually created on a branch, you cannot say that a commit "was done on a branch" after the fact. Branches may be added, deleted, renamed, or updated thereafter. The only thing you can tell is that a given commit is reachable from one or more branches at a given time. The `NameRevCommand` lists all the branches that a commit can be reached from.

Comment: BTW `revWalk.dispose()` is unnecessary since the RevWalk is disposed of in the `close()` method that is implicitly called in the try-with-resource block

Answer (score 8):

Different from most older VCS tools branch, a branch in Git is simply a lightweight movable pointer to one of these commits. It does not "contain" any commits itself. In other words, it's only a simple file that contains the 40 character SHA-1 checksum of the commit it points to. There's also a very illustrative example in [Git - Branches in a Nutshell](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell):

[image: A branch and its commit history]

As stated by Rüdiger Herrmann, while a commit is usually created on a branch, you cannot say that a commit "was done on a branch" after the fact. Branches may be added, deleted, renamed, or updated there after. For example, even if the branch or tag `v1.0` is removed, the commit `98ca9`, `34ac2`, `f30ab` are still there, and reachable by `master`. I would suggest you to read the [Pro Git (2nd Edition), Chapter 3.1 Git - Branches in a Nutshell](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell) for more detail.

As for JGit, here's my implementation of reading path for a specific commit:

```
private String getContent(RevCommit commit, String path) throws IOException {
  try (TreeWalk treeWalk = TreeWalk.forPath(git.getRepository(), path, commit.getTree())) {
    ObjectId blobId = treeWalk.getObjectId(0);
    try (ObjectReader objectReader = repo.newObjectReader()) {
      ObjectLoader objectLoader = objectReader.open(blobId);
      byte[] bytes = objectLoader.getBytes();
      return new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
  }
}
```